# Electron javascript post request returns code 400 error

Tags: javascript, electron

```
const STEAM_GET_PUBLISHED = "https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamRemoteStorage/GetPublishedFileDetails/v1/?itemcount=1&publishedfileids[0]=%id"; 

let targetURL = STEAM_GET_PUBLISHED.replace("%id", id);

$.post(targetURL, function (data, status) {
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

This is the result:

the request
[image: the request]

the error
[image: the error]

`itemcount` is clearly there, so I'm not sure what I did wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required params need to be sent as POST data, but you're sending them as URL query-string params.

This works:

```
const url = 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamRemoteStorage/GetPublishedFileDetails/v1/';

let postData = {
    itemcount: 1,
    publishedfileids: {
        0: 33
    }
};

jQuery.post(url, postData, function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```